# Missing resource ccny_rgbd_tools

Tags: ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm trying to install ccny_rgdb_tools so that i can make the mapping of a room with a kinect camera. When i reached the comand "Install any dependencies using rosdep:" it gives me the following error.

duarte@duarte-Aspire-V3-551G:~$ rosdep install ccny_rgbd_tools
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource ccny_rgbd_tools
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/duarte/ros
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/

How can i fix this? please help.
Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92206/missing-resource-ccny_rgbd_tools/) by [sigmaduarte](https://answers.ros.org/users/7181/sigmaduarte/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep install installs system dependencies of a package it expects to find already installed on your system.  Make sure you have followed all the steps earlier in whatever tututorial you're following(ps please link to the tutorial you are following).

Update:

The tutorial you link to is not quite linear to copy and paste and follow.  I think you're missing this step called out at the top:

and make sure it's added to your$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sigmaduarte](https://answers.ros.org/users/7181/sigmaduarte/) on 2013-10-21**:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep - this is the tutorial i followed to install rosdep. It doesnt give me any type of errors or warnings.
https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_rgbd_tools- is the turotial i used to install ccny-ros-pkg

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-10-21**:
@sigmaduarte : I agree with tfoote, I think you have forgotten to add the ccny package to your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. I am trying to install it to and I manage this step but have a compilation error
"rgbd_frame.cpp:276:69: erreur: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘cloud.pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ::header.std_msgs........" Keep me up to date if you have the same problem or not. Thanks

**Comment by [sigmaduarte](https://answers.ros.org/users/7181/sigmaduarte/) on 2013-10-24**:
It worked untill i tried the comand rosmake ccny_rgbd_tools.
I get the same exact error that you get, @CarolineQ : did you find out how to fix it?

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-10-24**:
Thanks for your answer, it's important to know that other people have the same error. I didn't find how to fix it but I opened a new question here http://answers.ros.org/question/93096/ccny_rgbd-compilation-error/ and here https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_rgbd_tools/issues/28